# How to make the menu in react-native picture? iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, menu, native

Yes, I am new among you, I want to make the application I made with react-native for ios the menu in the picture below. How can I do?
[i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpy0g.png)

[want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7oo9.png)

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: my project has more than one code file I don't get an error anywhere, how can I make the menu in the picture